# Get the whole value with decimal from input type number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a input field of type number. And I want to retrieve the exact value entered by the user without losing the focus.

1. When user enter `1` it should return `1`
2. When user enter `11` it should return `11`
3. When user enter `11`. it should return `11.` (but it returns the value without decimal - 11)

What I have tried:
I tried keyup event but the value for the element always came without decimal. And also tried the `modelctrl.parsers.push()` but parsers do not fired when the input is decimal(dot).

I have checked the `modelctrl.$viewValue`, `modelctrl.$modelValue`. Everything is returning the value without decimal.

I dont know the correct event on which it will return the complete value.

Comment: Any feedback or suggestions user24..?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like in this [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74zumvx6/3/). This is the right way to handle float values in JavaScript / AngularJS / HTML5.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="number" 
         step="0.01" 
         ng-class="{ 'error' : error }" 
         ng-model="test" 
         ng-change="change()" />
  <br >
  Number output: {{ test | number:2 }}
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = 0.2;
    $scope.error = false;

    $scope.change = function () {

      console.log($scope.test);

      if (!$scope.test) {
            $scope.error = true;
      } else {
            $scope.error = false;
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using this on mobile. So, how the user will enter other values if it is already append the float values. And what if user enter more than one decimal(dot).

Comment: @user2436548 I added an error handling. This should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
No: <input type="text" ng-model="no" ng-change="changeNoDecimal(no)"><br>
{{no1}}
</div>


<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.changeNoDecimal = function(no){
        $scope.no1 = Number(no).toFixed(2);
    }   
});
</script>
```